# send list as a parameter with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i want to send a list as parameter with ajax but in my function parameter is null. i can solve this problem with json but IE 7 do not support json.this is my code. how can i solve this????

```
 $(function () {
     $('#DeleteUser').click(function () {
         var list = [];
         $('#userForm input:checked').each(function () {
             list.push(this.id);
         });
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "UserManagement")',
             data: {
                 userId: list
             },
             type: 'POST',
             success: function (result) {
                 alert("success");
             },
             error: function (result) {
                 alert("error!");
             }
         }); //end ajax
     });
 });
```

Comment: 2 things you can try (have had this happen to me before), to your ajax call, add "datatype: 'application/json'" and/or "tradional: true".  Hope it works

Comment: is this within a cshtml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find the answer.check this site  http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/

Answer (score 0):

Add Douglas Crockford's famous json2.js, and use feature detection to polyfill json serialization for compatibility

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

from documentation:

```
JSON.stringify(value, replacer, space)
value       any JavaScript value, usually an object or array.

replacer    an optional parameter that determines how object
            values are stringified for objects. It can be a
            function or an array of strings.

space       an optional parameter that specifies the indentation
            of nested structures. If it is omitted, the text will
            be packed without extra whitespace. If it is a number,
            it will specify the number of spaces to indent at each
            level. If it is a string (such as '\t' or '&nbsp;'),
            it contains the characters used to indent at each level.
```

proposed code change:

```
{ ... data: JSON.stringify(list) ... }
```

Comment: i just add json2.js to my page and change data as you say it still send null to my list

Answer (score 0):

There might be a few reasons why this would fail

From the code it would seem you a using razor. If this is not in a razor view (Ie a `.cshtml` file) your link will be incorrect.

If the link is correct then the code would work assuming that your controller is setup correctly. Since the data will not be part of the URL you need to specify `FromBody` for the userId parameter.

```
public ActionResult DeleteUser([FromBody] userId){
    //implementation
}
```

alternatively then you could append the list to the URL

```
url: '@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "UserManagement")/' + list
```

and of course have a route in global.asax that sends the first argument to userId

Comment: You'll need to provide more information if you wish to have more help. The concept does work so what doesn't work is in the specifics only you know

Comment: i do all of the above except "and of course have a route in global.asax that sends the first argument to userId"(i dont know what u mean??) in my action parameter is null as before